# Ayuda con error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, javascript, json

Llevo unos días dándole vueltas a este código, y aunque me inserta los datos en la base de datos (he comprobado también con el console.log que me realiza el alta correctamente) me da el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Señalo la línea 142 en el código de abajo.

Os dejo el código por si me podéis ayudar a ver donde está el fallo, ya que le he dado mil vueltas y lo he hecho de distintos modos y siempre me sale el mismo fallo.

Es un formulario donde hay un combo de pacientes de una tabla, un combo de profesionales de otra tabla y los propios de la tabla. Abajo os adjunto una imagen de la base de datos.

altaDieta.js

```
//# sourceURL=altaDieta.js;

cargarDesplegableProfesionales();
cargarDesplegablePacientes();

function cargarDesplegableProfesionales() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "altaDieta/getProfesionales.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: true, // por defecto
        method: "GET",
        success: procesarGetProfesionales
    });
}

function procesarGetProfesionales(oDatos) {
    var sOptions = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < oDatos.length; i++) {

        sOptions += '<option value="' + oDatos[i].id_profesional + '">';
        sOptions += oDatos[i].nombre + " " + oDatos[i].apellidos;
        sOptions += '</option>';
    }

    $("#cmbProfesional").html(sOptions);
}

function cargarDesplegablePacientes() {
    var oArrayPacientes = null;

    // Existe en almacenamiento local
    if (localStorage["pacientes"] != null) {
        oArrayPacientes = JSON.parse(localStorage["pacientes"]);

        rellenaCombo(oArrayPacientes);


    } else {

        $.get('altaDieta/getPacientes.php', null, tratarGetPacientes, 'json');
    }
}

function rellenaCombo(oArrayPacientes) {
    $("#cmbPaciente").empty();

    $.each(oArrayPacientes, function (i, elemento) {

        $('<option value="' + elemento.id_paciente + '" >' + elemento.nombre + '</option>').appendTo("#cmbPaciente");

    });

}

function tratarGetPacientes(oArrayPacientes, sStatus, oXHR) {

    rellenaCombo(oArrayPacientes);

    // Guardar en localStorage
    localStorage["paciente"] = JSON.stringify(oArrayPacientes);
}

$("#aceptarCrearDieta").click(fCrearDieta);

function fCrearDieta() {
    let sProfesional = frmCrearDieta.cmbProfesional.value;
    let sPaciente = frmCrearDieta.cmbPaciente.value;
    let sTipo = frmCrearDieta.selectTipoDieta.value;
    let dFecha = frmCrearDieta.date.value.trim();
    let sObservaciones = frmCrearDieta.txtObservaciones.value.trim();
    let bValido = true;
    let sError = "";
    limpiarErrores();


    if (sTipo == 0) {
        bValido = false;
        sError += "\nDebe elegir un tipo de Dieta";
        frmCrearDieta.selectTipoDieta.classList.add("error");
        frmCrearDieta.selectTipoDieta.focus();
    }


    let oExpRegObservaciones = /^[^$%&|<>#]*$/;
    if (oExpRegObservaciones.test(sObservaciones) == false) {
        bValido = false;
        sError += "\nDebe escribir la Observaciones";
        frmCrearDieta.txtObservaciones.classList.add("error");
        frmCrearDieta.txtObservaciones.focus();
    }


    if (bValido == false) {
        alert(sError);
    } else {
        //Llamada POST ayax

        let oDieta = {
            id_profesional: sProfesional,
            id_paciente: sPaciente,
            tipo: sTipo,
            fecha: dFecha,
            observaciones: sObservaciones
        };


        // Instanciar objeto Ajax
        var oAjax = instanciarXHR();

        // Parametros
        let sParametros = "datos=" + JSON.stringify(oDieta);
        sParametros = encodeURI(sParametros);

        //Configurar la llamada --> Asincrono por defecto
        oAjax.open("POST", "altaDieta/altaDieta.php");

        //Asociar manejador de evento de la respuesta
        oAjax.addEventListener("readystatechange", respuestaAltaDieta, false);

        // Cabecera POST
        oAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        //Hacer la llamada
        oAjax.send(sParametros);


        //let parametros = "datos=" + JSON.stringify(oDieta);
        //$.post("altaDieta/altaDieta.php", encodeURI(parametros), respuestaAltaDieta, "json");

    }

    function respuestaAltaDieta() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let oDatos = this.responseText;
            console.log(oDatos);

            //oDatos = $.parseJSON(data);

(Línea 142) oDatos = JSON.parse(oDatos);

            if (oDatos.error) {
                alert(oDatos.mensaje);
            } else {
                alert(oDatos.mensaje);
                frmCrearDieta.reset();
                $("#frmCrearDieta").hide("normal");
            }
        }

    }

    function limpiarErrores() {
        frmCrearDieta.txtObservaciones.classList.remove("error");
        frmCrearDieta.selectTipoDieta.classList.remove("error");


    }
}


function instanciarXHR() {
    var xhttp = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else // code for IE5 and IE6
    {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xhttp;
}
```

altaDieta.php

```
<?php

// Configuración BASE DE DATOS MYSQL
$servidor  = "localhost";
$basedatos = "nutrilife";
$usuario   = "root";
$password  = "";

// Recojo los datos de entrada
$datosJSON = $_POST["datos"];
//Decodifico el objeto dieta
$dieta = json_decode($datosJSON);

// Creamos la conexión al servidor.
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password,$basedatos) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
mysqli_query($conexion,"utf8");
$sql ="select * from dietas";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
$fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
$sql = "INSERT INTO dietas VALUES (null,$dieta->id_profesional,$dieta->id_paciente,'$dieta->tipo','$dieta->fecha','$dieta->observaciones');";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

if ($resultado){
    $respuesta["error"] = 0;
    $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Alta realizada"; 
} else {
    $respuesta["error"] = 1;
    $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Error en el proceso de alta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
}

echo json_encode($respuesta);

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Y esta es mi base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en tu error pone que salta en la línea 142, pulsando ahi te lleva a la función exacta que falla, con eso puedes acotar el problema y mostrarnos más claramente que puede ser

Comment: El error 142 me lleva a :  oDatos = JSON.parse(oDatos);
Lo voy a señalar en el código.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.

Apoyándome de momento en la imagen que colocas (primer error que se muestra) en tu PHP se genera un error; particularmente en la línea del `mysqli_query` (ver [manual php mysqlli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)); efectivamente tiene al menos 2 parámetros obligatorio el 1ro. el `$conexion`, sin embargo el 2do (que debe ser un Query) estas pasando **uft8**; este debe ser (en tu momento) un `SELECT`.

Así mismo revisa que el PHP no devuelvas mas que (en tu caso como se ve en ilustración):

```
{"error":0, "mensaje":"Alta realizada"}
```

cualquier otra cosa fuera de elementos procesados para devolver con el `json_encode` hara que tu json sea erroneo y te genere diversos errores no tan facil de detectar salvo veas la salida (como en la imagen) de lo que estas recibiendo.